What’s the difference between “לְדָוִד מִזְמוֹר” and “מִזְמוֹר לְדָוִד” in Tehilim?
Tehilim 110 for example begins with “l’David mizmor”, while 108 starts with “mizmor l’David”. Is there a difference in meaning? Does one denote authorship and the other does not?

https://outorah.org/p/3592/

@rosends Which ultimately is from Pesachim 117a.
